# Hover наведения на блок

Tags: html, css, hover

Html

```
<div class="post">
                        <div class="post_ic1">
                            <div class="ps_data">
                                <h5 class="dat_tx">30</h5>
                                <h5 class="dat_tx">.Sep</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <h2 class="post_h2 post_h2_active">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
                               <p>Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium.</p>
                        <a href="#">Read More
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

Надо сделать так, чтобы при наведении на блок `post` менялись цвет `"h2 class="post_h2", p`, также фон и цвет блоков `class=dat_tx`
[image: Сейчас]

должно быть так 
[image: так]

Answer (score 3):

Вот так это делается : смотрите сниппет

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#909090;
  padding:0 6px;
}
a:hover{
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
.card{
  width:300px;
  min-height:100px;
  margin:30px 10px;
  padding:0;
  background:#eee;
  color:#909090;
  font-size:20px;
  transition:background .5s;
}
.card:hover{
  background:#b7e8ef;
  color:#111;
}
.card:hover img{
   filter: grayscale(0%);
  -webkit-filter:grayscale(0%); 
}
.card:hover a{
  color:#fff;
  animation:link 1s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes link{
  from{
    background:red;
  }
}
img{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);
  transition:all .5s;
}
img:hover{
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  -webkit-filter:grayscale(0%);  
}
.images{
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.imgPosition{
  position:absolute;
  top:-250px;
}
.text{
  text-align:justify;
  width:98%;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="card"> 
 <div class="images"> 
  <div class="imgPosition">
  <img src="http://avakartinki.ru/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/avatarka_nout08.jpg" alt="девушка с ноутбуком">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="text">
 <p>
That is preciously how this string was constructed. Default text is for web developers and designers that need default text quickly.
</p>
 </div>
 <div class="link">
   <a href="">читать далее</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ссылка на codepen : http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/QEJQPR?editors=110

Answer (score 2):

Просто опишите все требуемые стили в блоках типа такого:

```
post:hover .post_h2{
    color: red;
}
```

Так как вы не сказали конкретно, какие стили нужны, то я не могу предоставить готовый код.